# ODBC drivers run in kernel space or user space? Why?

Tags: database, odbc, ipc

I'm studying databases now and I'd like to know if ODBC drivers really run in kernel space. Wouldn't it be easier just to use sockets for client connections? The only reasonable explanation I can think is that it would be performance issue with sockets. Or there are other reasons?

Comment: Why do you think the ODBC driver runs in kernel space?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Because it's called "driver". I only know about device drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ODBC isn't a protocol! It's an API. ODBC isn't about how to talk with DBMS. It's about how to talk with a thing that know how to talk with DBMS. That thing is a C library. It's called "DBMS-specific library" or "ODBC-driver". ODBC specifies what C functions (and names of this functions) a library must have so that can be used as an ODBC-driver. ODBC-driver implements DBMS-specific protocol. It can use whatever it wants to talk with DBMS: sockets, pipes, shared-memory, pigeons, whatever

Also there is an interesting thing called "ODBC-ODBC bridge". It allows you to connect to DBMS remotely without having locally installed DBMS-specific library. Similar to a protocol, isn't it?

2. User-space driver is pretty common thing. So it's not weird that ODBC-libraries are called "drivers". It's very convenient to implement all logic in user-space and use kernel-space only to send data to device.